# How can I put a \t (and only that) as an XML value in a tag in C#

Tags: c#, xml, separator

```
<xml file>
    <stuff>
         <separator>\t</separator>
    </stuff>
</xml file>
```

I would like to just get a tab separator from this using `XmlTextReader reader`.  But when I use

```
string SEPARATOR = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
```

a double "\t" (two slashes before the t) gets put in a string.  I would just like to have a \t that would represent a separator.

I've also tried:

```
<separator>&#x9</separator>
<separator>&#x009</separator>
<separator>![CDATA[&#x9;]]</separator>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are getting only a single slash. Are you looking at the value in the debugger? The debugger shows an escape character.

Comment: What problem do you get with using the hex value in a CDATA block?

Comment: Why not just put the ASCII representation (9) and then convert after reading?

Comment: The extra \ is the debugger escaping

Comment: @DStanley I get '[CDATA[ ]]' when I use the hex value in a CDATA block.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose The OP does not _want_ the slash - the XML contains a literal slash character when the OP wants the tab character.

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: @DStanley Misunderstood it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax for both special characters and CDATA is not correct. Try:

```
<separator>&#09;</separator>
```

or

```
<separator><![CDATA[&#x9;]]></separator>
```

Comment: I didn't try the second one.